# Forward reference in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, forward-reference

What is the difference of the following regular expressions?

```
(\2amigo|(go!))+
(amigo|(go!))+
```

They both match the same strings.
https://regexr.com/3u62t

How does the forward reference work?

Comment: In ECMAScript, every backreference is pre-initialized with an empty string. In PCRE, it would not match the same strings.

Comment: Please update the question with what you expect the pattern to fetch from the provided strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't actually work at all (though as Wiktor Stribiżew pointed out, it could with other regex flavours).

When `\n` refers to a capture group that has not captured anything, it matches the empty string. You can see this in e.g. `/(a)?b\1/`, which matches `b`.

When `\n` refers to a capture group that appears later in the pattern, it ordinarily cannot have captured anything yet. You can see this in e.g. `/\1b(a)/`, which matches `ba`.

You might think that within a repetition, the previous captures are persisted, so that `/(\2a(b))*/` would match `abbab`, but that's not how it works: within a repetition, when a new match starts, the captures are reset. So instead it matches `abab`, *not* `abbab`.

As a result, a forward reference is completely and utterly useless and only ever matches an empty string. There is no difference between your two patterns.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I meant it doesn't actually work at all as a forward reference. It never references anything that's been captured.

Comment: By the way, It took this from https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/forward-references/problem

Comment: @kame That starts with "NOTE - Forward reference is supported by JGsoft, .NET, Java, Perl, PCRE, PHP, Delphi and Ruby regex flavors. " -- JavaScript is not listed, and it is right not to be. Are you sure JavaScript is what you want to ask about?

Comment: @kame Please take care when editing your question to do it in such a way that it does not totally invalidate existing answers. In this case, simply changing the tags was not really appropriate anyway, since you still use a JavaScript example which doesn't demonstrate what you intended to edit the question to ask instead. At any rate, for .NET, the "you might think that ..." part is actually true (and the "it matches the empty string" is false); that should tell you how it works.

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: @kame I am not really sure. One option is reverting your question to ask about only JavaScript and optionally ask a new question about .NET (making sure to use an online demo that uses .NET regular expressions) if you are still looking for more details about that. It is possible that there is a better option that I am not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The second "(amigo|(go!))+" captures: amigoamigo

The first "(\2amigo|(go!))+ " doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior depends on the language.

In Ruby and Perl forward references can also be used, but be sure the referenced parenthesis
has matched when is going to be used. This usually means that the forward reference
is inside some repetition group. For example, in Ruby this regexp matches with `train` only if
it is prefixed by at least one `choo`:

```rb
$ irb
irb(main):052:0> regex = /(\2train|(choo))+/
=> /(\2train|(choo))+/
irb(main):053:0> 'choochootrain' =~ regex
=> 0
irb(main):054:0> $&
=> "choochootrain"
irb(main):055:0> $1
=> "chootrain"
irb(main):056:0> $2
=> "choo"
irb(main):004:0> 'train' =~ regex
=> nil
```

This is not the case in JavaScript:

```js
[~/.../github-actions/225-github-actions-demo(master)]$ node
Welcome to Node.js v13.5.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> regex = /(\2train|(choo))+/
/(\2train|(choo))+/
> regex.exec('train')
[
  'train',
  'train',
  undefined,
  index: 0,
  input: 'train',
  groups: undefined
]
```

In fact, it does match `train` (The `\2` is assumed empty):