# RegEx for matching forward reference exercise

Tags: regex

I am working on an exercise on regex forward reference like the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51929089/forward-reference-in-regex)

The task is:

- string *s* consists of **tic** or **tac**
- **tic** should not be immediate neighbour of itself
- The first **tic** must occur only when **tac** has appeared at least twice before

I've used this `regex` to solve it. But it doesn't use `forward reference` so I really want to know how this can be solved using it.

```
^tac(tac)+(tic(tac)+){0,}(tic)?$
```

**Valid**:

```
tactactic
tactactictactic
```

**Invalid**:

```
tactactictactictictac
tactictac
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Your own regex fails to match on strings with more than two `tac`s at beginning e.g. `tactactactic`. You got your answer already but in case of performance you should choose a lighter regex: `^(tac)(\1+tic)+\1*$`

Comment: @revo That is also a great solution, why not post it?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I feel like it doesn't answer the question because OP explicitly asks for a solution with forward references involved which is already given.

Comment: @revo You're right, I guess the exercise did not have enough cases. And yours works great too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses a forward reference:

```
^(\2tic|(tac))+$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gp8CJs/1.)

It's actually very similar to the example given on [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref2.html).

Comment: Thank you. I've been trying how `forward reference` could be used to solve and this is it

Answer (score 0):

If there should be at least 2 tics in the string, you might use a negative lookahead to assert that there is no tictic present and start by matching and least 2 times `tic`

```
^(?!.*tictic)(?:tac){2}tic(?:t[ai]c)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/woJ1yw/1/)

If the string can also consist of only 1 or more time tac, you could use an alternation:

```
^(?:(?:tac)+|(?!.*(tictic))(?:tac){2,}tic(?:t[ia]c)*)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?:tac)+` Repeat 1+ times only tac
  - `|` Or
  - `(?!.*(tictic))` Assert what is on the right does not contain tactac
  - `(?:tac){2,}(?:t[ia]c)*` Repeat 2+ times tac followed by tic and repeat tic or tac 0+ times until the end of the string
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yT34oD/1)

Comment: didn't quite get the part about `tempered greedy token` but can you show one involving `forward reference` as well? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This simple regex should be good enough without any look arounds or tempered greedy token as they are quite expensive in terms of matching.

```
^tac(tac(?:tic)?)+$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^tac` - Start of string with `tac`
- `(tac(?:tic)?)+` - This matches `tac` optionally followed by `tic` due to which no two `tic` will ever occur together, and since `tic` is optional here, hence it allows matching of `tac` as many times as needed to match the pattern.
- `$` - End of string

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sDCWrs/1)**

Comment: Shouldn't `tactactactictactic` be valid?

Comment: You both are right. Taken care both of the patterns. Please check

Comment: Thanks for answering, but can you also accommodate `forward reference` (but not in a redundant way)

Comment: @greeny1234: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you call `forward reference`. Do you mean positive look ahead?

Comment: I've put a link in the question

Comment: Ok lemme check.